# How to save SQL Data/Close DB on applicationDidEnterBackground and resume on applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: iphone, sql

I have an app with 4 or 5 SQL Tables open.

When the user taps the home button and applicationDidEnterBackground is called I save all dirty records into the tables:

```
[self.shoppingListArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(saveAllData)];
```

...

```
- (void)saveAllData {
    if(isDirty) {
        if(updateStmt == nil) { 
            const char *sql = "UPDATE ShoppingList SET Section = ?, Question = ?, Checked = ?, Modified = ? WHERE ID = ?";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        NSLog(@"DIRTY Item Was Updated: %@", Question);

        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [Section UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [Question UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, isChecked ? [@"YES" UTF8String]:[@"NO" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 4, isModified ? [@"YES" UTF8String]:[@"NO" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt,  5, ID);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);

        isDirty = NO;
    }
    //Reclaim all memory here.
    [Section release];
    Section = nil;
    [Question release];
    Question = nil;
    isDetailViewHydrated = NO;
}
```

Then I finalize statements and close database:

```
[ShoppingListInformation finalizeStatements];
```

...

```
+ (void) finalizeStatements {
    if(database) sqlite3_close(database);
    if(deleteStmt) sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
    if(updateStmt) sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
    if(addStmt) sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
}
```

So, the question is what do I do when applicationWillEnterForeground is called?

Do I reopen databases and repopulate my arrays and reload table views?

What is the best practice of how to approach this and not lose user data, restore state, etc?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Comment: Ha! Ive heard of FMDB so I should look more into that. I've heard other users comment that if you don't know what you're doing with CoreData you can really get yourself in a mess?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not closing the db or finalizing statements unless the app is closing (applicationWillTerminate:).  Then you will come back into the app in the same state you left it, no action required.  I'm not positive this is the most efficient way to do it but it has worked for me.

Comment: That's what I've been doing but I'm fearful of users losing data.  What if user does a hard reset of phone when the app is suspended?  I'm not sure but I don't think applicationWillTerminate will ever fire in that case which may result in loss of data? I guess I could test it on the device.. Thanks for your input nonetheless!

Comment: You don't have to close the db or finalize statements in order to save the data to the db.  You would still call saveAllData when you go into the background.